# React-awesome-reveal not appearing on scroll

Tags: reactjs, fade

So I'm working on a website and I want to content to fade in as the user scrolls. I have looked at multiple options but struggled with others so tried react-awesome-reveal (if you know an easy alternative I will be willing to try that).

So currently when I open my home tab, the first header does the transition correctly, but the other elements are already loaded when you scroll down.
I also tried putting all the elements into 1 Fade component with cascade and that did not work either.

A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
import { Fade} from "react-awesome-reveal";
import SliderItem from './SliderItem'
```

(this is within the return section)

```
 <Fade direction='up' casecade triggerOnce='true' duration={2000}>
              <div className='first-header original'>
                  <h1>LET'S GET <div className="physical">PHYSICAL.</div></h1>
                  <div className='headerImg'>
                      <img src={headerImg}></img>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </Fade>       
   
              <Fade direction='up' casecade triggerOnce='true'>
                <div className='second-header'>
                    <video autoPlay loop muted playsInline className='backVideo'>
                        <source src={video}/>
                    </video>
                    
                    <div className='content'>
                      <h1 class="text2">#GetShopping</h1>
                      <img className='second-scribble' src={scribble2}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </Fade> 
             

              
              <Fade direction='up' casecade triggerOnce='true'>
                <div className='third-header'>
                    <Carousel>
                            {products}
                    </Carousel> 
                </div>
              </Fade>

            

              <Fade direction='up' casecade triggerOnce='true'>
                <div className='info-header'>

                    <div className='content-img'>
                        <img src={skateGirl}></img>
                    </div>
            
                    <div className='content-text'>
                    <img className='third-scribble' src={scribble3}/>
                        <small>SKY SKATES IS FOR EVERYONE</small>
                        <h2>Join the Squad</h2>
                        <p>Sky Skates is a worldwide community for those who love to skate. Take your pick from our roller skates, inline skates or skateboards - there is something for everyone.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </Fade>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the same issue I was facing.
After tinkering around with the react-awesome-reveal,
I was finally able to figure out the solution.

Removing all other **triggerOnce** props should solve all of the transition on scroll issues. 
This issue particularly appears when more than one **triggerOnce** prop exist in the return expression.